# PHP download a specific row from database table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, datatables

I'm learning PHP right now and connecting to MySQL. I'm able to connect to a table called "info" and display the "date", "time", and "data" of each row, along with 2 extra columns that will allow the user to download the respective "data" into a txt and csv. This is where I'm completely lost on how to achieve that.

My understanding is that since it'll be a clickable link, I will have to use "href=" and will link that to a separate php that I create that will download that row's data, right? But then how does that new php file know which row to download from? I'm guessing I need to pass the row number it is to the other file?

Greatly appreciate it if anyone can lead me in the right direction or have examples. Thanks!

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT date, time, data FROM info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td> Date </td><td>Time</td><td>Data</td><td> Download text </td><td> Download csv</td>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td><td>" . $row["time"]. "</td><td>" .$row["data"] ."</td><td><a href='NEEDTXTFILE.php'>".$row["date"].'.txt'. "</a></td>"."<td><a href='NEEDCSVFILE.php'>".$row["date"].'.csv'. "</a></td> ";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: post contents/logic for `NEEDTXTFILE.PHP` & other one too. And use link in format of `needFile.php?type=txt& date=date`

Comment: you should pass to the `NEEDCSVFILE.php` a reference to the row you need eg: `NEEDCSVFILE.php?id=23`

Comment: @DavChana Sorry, super new to php. What do you mean by needFile.php?type=txt& date=date ? I also haven't gotten to any contents/logic for NEEDTXTFILE. I'm not even sure if I'm heading in the right direction right now

Comment: @scaisEdge that makes sense, but how do I find out what the id is?

Comment: Yes, as above guy said, use one single php; tell it you need txt and this date by using ?type=txt&date=20171021 all these parameters are available in $_GET array; also need to set mime type headers in php file to tell browsers its sending txt gile; and that its downloable.

Comment: @id is which row you want to send to user

Comment: @DavChana so for this example, it would look something like href="NEEDTXTFILE.php"?type=txt&date=20171021 right? Could I do something like href="NEEDTXTFILE.php"?type=txt&date=.$row["date"]. ?

Comment: tipically is the id of the row you need .. i have posted  a brief answer  .. hope is useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you select also the id value

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, date, time, data FROM info";


    ....
```

you could add the id to your href  eg:

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["date"]. "</td><td>" .
                     $row["time"]. "</td><td>" .
                     $row["data"] .
                     "</td><td><a href='NEEDTXTFILE.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "'>".
                     $row["date"].'.txt'. "</a></td>"."<td><a href='NEEDCSVFILE.php'>".
                     $row["date"].'.csv'. "</a></td> ";
          echo "</tr>";    
      }
```

then in your  `NEEDTXTFILE.php`  you can obtain the id in `$_GET['id']`